# UILabel font size?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, fonts, uilabel, font-size

I can't seem to modify the font size of a UILabel with the following code:

```
itemTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
```

As i increase the number 25 to something greater, it seems to only add a top margin to the label, which consequently pushes the text down so much, so that the text gets cut off at the bottom or completely overflows.

i have another UILabel elsewhere with systemFontOfSize 25, and it's much smaller than the itemTitle text.  What's going on?  Isn't 25 supposed to be an absolute value?

i am so confused on how to programmatically change font size of uilabels.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Check that your labels aren't set to automatically resize. In IB, it's called "Autoshrink" and is right beside the font setting. Programmatically, it's called `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

Answer (score 180):

I have modified the UILabel by following code:

```
label.font=[label.font fontWithSize:25];
```

Try this and see whether is it working in your case or not???

Comment: `label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(25)` for Swift

Comment: Swift 3
`label.font = label.font.withSize(25)`

Answer (score 35):

```
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9]];
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 23):

For **Swift 3.1**, **Swift 4** and  **Swift 5**, if you only want change the font size for a label :

```
let myLabel : UILabel = ...
myLabel.font = myLabel.font.withSize(25)
```

Answer (score 12):

### **You can set font size by these properties **

```
timedisplayLabel= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 194, 180, 60)];

[timedisplayLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

[timedisplayLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[timedisplayLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

[timedisplayLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[timedisplayLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

[timedisplayLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:60]];

timedisplayLabel.layer.shadowColor =[[UIColor whiteColor ]CGColor ];

timedisplayLabel.layer.shadowOffset=(CGSizeMake(0, 0));

timedisplayLabel.layer.shadowOpacity=1;

timedisplayLabel.layer.shadowRadius=3.0;

timedisplayLabel.layer.masksToBounds=NO;

timedisplayLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

timedisplayLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me in

**Swift 3**

```
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(40.0)
```

**Swift 4**

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(40.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

very simple, yet effective method to adjust the size of label text progmatically :-

```
label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:36];
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sequencerPlayLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kTypeFont size:kTypeFontSize];
```

-rich

Answer (score 1):

Answers above helped greatly.

Here is the Swift version.

```
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

*.... lines of code later*

self.priceLabel.font = self.priceLabel.font.fontWithSize(22)
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# These ways you can Solve the problem, In UIkit these methods are available.

```
Label.Font = Label.Font.WithSize(5.0f);
       Or
Label.Font = UIFont.FromName("Copperplate", 10.0f);  
       Or
Label.Font = UIFont.WithSize(5.0f);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your label frame size height and width so your text not cut.

```
 [label setframe:CGRect(x,y,widht,height)];
```