# Animating UILabel Font Size Change

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uilabel

I am currently making an application that uses a custom View Controller container. Multiple views are on the screen at one time and when one is tapped, the selected view controller animates to full screen. In doing so, the selected view controllers subviews scale as well (frame, font size, etc.) Though, UILabel's font property is not animatable leading to issues. I have tried multiple solutions but all flat out suck.

The solutions I have tried are:

1. Take a screenshot of the larger view and animating the change (similar to how Flipboard does)
2. Animate by using the transform property
3. Zooming out a UIScrollView and zooming it in when brought to full screen.
4. Setting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to YES and setting the fontSize prior to animation

One has been the best solution so far but I am not satisfied with it.

I'm looking for other suggestions if anyone has any or a UILabel substitue that animates smoothly using [UIView animate..].

Here is a good example that is similar to what I would like my UILabel to do:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/zoomingviewcontroller-to-animate-uiview.html

**EDIT: This code works**

```
// Load View

self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.label.text = @"TEXT";
self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.label sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:self.label];

// Animation

self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:80.0];
self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.label.transform, .25, .25);
[self.label sizeToFit];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.label.transform, 4.0, 4.0);
    self.label.center = self.view.center;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:80.0]; 
    self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.label.transform, 1.0, 1.0);

    [self.label sizeToFit];

}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can font size of UILabel be changed with smooth animation on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098893/can-font-size-of-uilabel-be-changed-with-smooth-animation-on-iphone)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can change the size and font of your `UILabel` with animation like below .. here I just put the example of how to change the font of `UILabel` with transform Animation ..

```
    yourLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35]; // set font size which you want instead of 35
    yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(yourLabel.transform, 0.35, 0.35); 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(yourLabel.transform, 5, 5);
    }];
```

Comment: I have tried this. It seems as though the transform happens from the center point. When I am animating the scale up effect it seems display at a different rate than the frame change. I'm probably not making much sense but the animation does not replicate in the same manner the scaling of UIImageViews does.

Comment: i do same thing with above code but i just change the size of lable and UIImageView... what you want exactly?? and whats the problem when you use above code??

Comment: @morcutt also if you want to change the font size with your lable size.. means adjust with your lable size then use adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property of uilable, more info see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475513/uilabel-font-size

Comment: I have also tried adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. The animation occurs but the position is always off during the animation.

Comment: Accepted. A little tweaking and you got me what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: yes.. i think if you put that property with yes and then use above code then it may be worked right ?? and thanx :)

Comment: I ended up using your code you posted. Check the edit I made.

Comment: The only problem with this method is that `CGAffineTransform` does not account for font tracking. So, if one tried to scale a `UILabel` using San Francisco font, the scaled label would have incorrect tracking values.

Answer (score 49):

## For 2017 onwards....

**Swift 3.0,  4.0**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
     label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1) //Scale label area
 }
```

Critical:

## The critical point to avoid blurring is you must begin with the biggest size, and shrink it. Then expand to "1" when needed.

For quick "pops" (like a highlight animation) it's OK to expand beyond 1 but if you are transitioning between two sizes, *make the larger size the "correct" normal one*.

Comment: the only way to go !

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the font to become blurry if you need to scale it up by more than a tiny amount.

Comment: @AlexScanlan but you can change the fontSize after the animation finished, so its not blurry :)

Comment: Ah, @AlexScanlan it is **essential to begin with the larger sizes**, the largest size you will need, and shrink it to the smaller size.

Answer (score 27):

I've created `UILabel` extension in Swift.

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    func animate(font: UIFont, duration: TimeInterval) {
        // let oldFrame = frame
        let labelScale = self.font.pointSize / font.pointSize
        self.font = font
        let oldTransform = transform
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: labelScale, y: labelScale)
        // let newOrigin = frame.origin
        // frame.origin = oldFrame.origin // only for left aligned text
        // frame.origin = CGPoint(x: oldFrame.origin.x + oldFrame.width - frame.width, y: oldFrame.origin.y) // only for right aligned text
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            //L self.frame.origin = newOrigin
            self.transform = oldTransform
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Uncomment lines if the label text is left or right aligned.

Comment: What if the label was right aligned? The problem I'm running into is I have a right aligned label and when I use this code the label goes off to the right and is no longer aligned.

Comment: @JideO Updated answer.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only thing that really worked form me. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You could also use CATextLayer which has fontSize as an animatable property.

```
let startFontSize: CGFloat = 20
let endFontSize: CGFloat = 80

let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = "yourText"
textLayer.font = yourLabel.font.fontName as CFTypeRef?
textLayer.fontSize = startFontSize
textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale //for some reason CATextLayer by default only works for 1x screen resolution and needs this line to work properly on 2x, 3x, etc. ...
textLayer.frame = parentView.bounds
parentView.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

//animation:
let duration: TimeInterval = 1
textLayer.fontSize = endFontSize //because upon completion of the animation CABasicAnimation resets the animated CALayer to its original state (as opposed to changing its properties to the end state of the animation), setting fontSize to endFontSize right BEFORE the animation starts ensures the fontSize doesn't jump back right after the animation.
let fontSizeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fontSize")
fontSizeAnimation.fromValue = startFontSize
fontSizeAnimation.toValue = endFontSize
fontSizeAnimation.duration = duration
fontSizeAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
textLayer.add(fontSizeAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

I used it in my project: https://github.com/yinanq/AngelListJobs

This animation keeps the font top left aligned (unlike CGAffineTransformScale scaling the label from center), pro or con depending on your needs. A disadvantage of CATextLayer is that CALayers don't work with autolayout constraint animation (which I happened to need and solved it by making a UIView containing just the CATextLayer and animating its constraints).

Comment: @ShubhamNaik im guessing you didn't implement 2nd line under "//animation:" section in my answer above?

`textLayer.fontSize = endFontSize //because upon completion of the animation CABasicAnimation resets the animated CALayer to its original state (as opposed to changing its properties to the end state of the animation), setting fontSize to endFontSize right BEFORE the animation starts ensures the fontSize doesn't jump back right after the animation.`

resetting to fromValue is the behavior for any CABasicAnimation, luckily this solution is also universal for any CABasicAnimation

Comment: To keep the animation in its final state you can also do: 
`fontSizeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
fontSizeAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards`

Answer (score 12):

For those not looking for a transform, but actual value change:

```
UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
}) { isFinished in }
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly I've been looking for. This is the correct way of animating fonts without transformation of labels. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## For someone who wants to adjust direction of animation

I have created an extension for `UILabel` to animate font size change

```
extension UILabel {
  func animate(fontSize: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval) {
    let startTransform = transform
    let oldFrame = frame
    var newFrame = oldFrame
    let scaleRatio = fontSize / font.pointSize

    newFrame.size.width *= scaleRatio
    newFrame.size.height *= scaleRatio
    newFrame.origin.x = oldFrame.origin.x - (newFrame.size.width - oldFrame.size.width) * 0.5
    newFrame.origin.y = oldFrame.origin.y - (newFrame.size.height - oldFrame.size.height) * 0.5
    frame = newFrame

    font = font.withSize(fontSize)

    transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1 / scaleRatio, y: 1 / scaleRatio);
    layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
      self.transform = startTransform
      newFrame = self.frame
    }) { (Bool) in
      self.frame = newFrame
    }
  }
```

---

If you want to adjust direction of animation, use below method and put a suitable anchor point.

**SWIFT**

```
struct LabelAnimateAnchorPoint {
  // You can add more suitable archon point for your needs
  static let leadingCenterY         = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0.5)
  static let trailingCenterY        = CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 0.5)
  static let centerXCenterY         = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
  static let leadingTop             = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
}

extension UILabel {
  func animate(fontSize: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval, animateAnchorPoint: CGPoint) {
    let startTransform = transform
    let oldFrame = frame
    var newFrame = oldFrame
    let archorPoint = layer.anchorPoint
    let scaleRatio = fontSize / font.pointSize

    layer.anchorPoint = animateAnchorPoint

    newFrame.size.width *= scaleRatio
    newFrame.size.height *= scaleRatio
    newFrame.origin.x = oldFrame.origin.x - (newFrame.size.width - oldFrame.size.width) * animateAnchorPoint.x
    newFrame.origin.y = oldFrame.origin.y - (newFrame.size.height - oldFrame.size.height) * animateAnchorPoint.y
    frame = newFrame

    font = font.withSize(fontSize)

    transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1 / scaleRatio, y: 1 / scaleRatio);
    layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
      self.transform = startTransform
      newFrame = self.frame
    }) { (Bool) in
      self.layer.anchorPoint = archorPoint
      self.frame = newFrame
    }
  }
}
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
// You can add more suitable archon point for your needs
#define kLeadingCenterYAnchorPoint         CGPointMake(0.f, .5f)
#define kTrailingCenterYAnchorPoint        CGPointMake(1.f, .5f)
#define kCenterXCenterYAnchorPoint         CGPointMake(.5f, .5f)
#define kLeadingTopAnchorPoint             CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f)

@implementation UILabel (FontSizeAnimating)

- (void)animateWithFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animateAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)animateAnchorPoint {
  CGAffineTransform startTransform = self.transform;
  CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;
  __block CGRect newFrame = oldFrame;
  CGPoint archorPoint = self.layer.anchorPoint;
  CGFloat scaleRatio = fontSize / self.font.pointSize;

  self.layer.anchorPoint = animateAnchorPoint;

  newFrame.size.width *= scaleRatio;
  newFrame.size.height *= scaleRatio;
  newFrame.origin.x = oldFrame.origin.x - (newFrame.size.width - oldFrame.size.width) * animateAnchorPoint.x;
  newFrame.origin.y = oldFrame.origin.y - (newFrame.size.height - oldFrame.size.height) * animateAnchorPoint.y;
  self.frame = newFrame;

  self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
  self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 1.f / scaleRatio, 1.f / scaleRatio);
  [self layoutIfNeeded];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    self.transform = startTransform;
    newFrame = self.frame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.layer.anchorPoint = archorPoint;
    self.frame = newFrame;
  }];
}

@end
```

---

For example, to animate changing label font size to 30, duration 1s from center and scale bigger. Simply call

**SWIFT**

```
YOUR_LABEL.animate(fontSize: 30, duration: 1, animateAnchorPoint: LabelAnimateAnchorPoint.centerXCenterY)
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
[YOUR_LABEL animateWithFontSize:30 
                       duration:1 
             animateAnchorPoint:kCenterXCenterYAnchorPoint];
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0 & Swift 4.0**

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: { 

    label.transform = label.transform.scaledBy(x:4,y:4) //Change x,y to get your desired effect. 

    } ) { (completed) in

         //Animation Completed      

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found each of the suggestions here inadequate for these reasons:

1. They don't actually change the font size.
2. They don't play well with frame sizing & auto layout.
3. Their interface is non-trivial and/or doesn't play nice inside animation blocks.

In order to retain all of these features & still get a smooth animation transition I've combined the transform approach and the font approach.

The interface is simple.  Just update the `fontSize` property and you'll update the font's size.  Do this inside an animation block and it'll animate.

```
@interface UILabel(MPFontSize)

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat fontSize;

@end
```

As for the implementation, there's the simple way, and there's the better way.

Simple:

```
@implementation UILabel(MPFontSize)

- (void)setFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

    CGAffineTransform originalTransform = self.transform;
    UIFont *targetFont = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale( originalTransform,
                fontSize / self.fontSize, fontSize / self.fontSize );
    }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.transform = originalTransform;
        if (finished)
            self.font = targetFont;
    }];
}

- (CGFloat)fontSize {

    return self.font.pointSize;
};

@end
```

Now, the problem with this is that the layout can stutter upon completion, because the view's frame is sized based on the original font all the way until the animation completion, at which point the frame updates to accommodate the target font without animation.

Fixing this problem is a little harder because we need to override `intrinsicContentSize`.  You can do this either by subclassing `UILabel` or by swizzling the method.  I personally swizzle the method, because it lets me keep a generic `fontSize` property available to all `UILabel`s, but that depends on some library code I can't share here.  Here is how you would go about this using subclassing.

Interface:

```
@interface AnimatableLabel : UILabel

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat fontSize;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@interface AnimatableLabel()

@property(nonatomic) UIFont *targetFont;
@property(nonatomic) UIFont *originalFont;

@end

@implementation AnimatableLabel

- (void)setFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

    CGAffineTransform originalTransform = self.transform;
    self.originalFont = self.font;
    self.targetFont = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale( originalTransform,
                fontSize / self.fontSize, fontSize / self.fontSize );
    }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.transform = originalTransform;

        if (self.targetFont) {
            if (finished)
                self.font = self.targetFont;
            self.targetFont = self.originalFont = nil;
            [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
        }
    }];
}

- (CGFloat)fontSize {

    return self.font.pointSize;
};

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {

    @try {
        if (self.targetFont)
            self.font = self.targetFont;
        return self.intrinsicContentSize;
    }
    @finally {
        if (self.originalFont)
            self.font = self.originalFont;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Remember it's 2018, could you provide a **Swift** version of your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the text size from another anchor point, here is the **Swift 5** solution:

**How to apply:**

```swift
yourLabel.setAnimatedFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 48), duration: 0.2, anchorPointX: 0, anchorPointY: 1)
```

**Extensions:**

```swift
extension UILabel {
  /// Animate font size from a given anchor point of the label.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - duration: Animation measured in seconds
  ///   - anchorPointX: 0 = left, 0.5 = center, 1 = right
  ///   - anchorPointY: 0 = top, 0.5 = center, 1 = bottom
  func setAnimatedFont(_ font: UIFont, duration: TimeInterval, anchorPointX: CGFloat, anchorPointY: CGFloat) {
    guard let oldFont = self.font else { return }

    setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: anchorPointX, y: anchorPointY))
    self.font = font

    let scaleFactor = oldFont.pointSize / font.pointSize
    let oldTransform = transform
    transform = transform.scaledBy(x: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
      self.transform = oldTransform
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
}

extension UIView {
  /// Change the anchor point without moving the view's position.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - point: The layer's bounds rectangle.
  func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
    let oldOrigin = frame.origin
    layer.anchorPoint = point
    let newOrigin = frame.origin

    let translation = CGPoint(x: newOrigin.x - oldOrigin.x, y: newOrigin.y - oldOrigin.y)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    center = CGPoint(x: center.x - translation.x, y: center.y - translation.y)
  }
}
```