# Change size of label's frame with animation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, label, frame

I would like to know if there is a way to change a label's **frame**'s width (not the fontSize or something) with a smooth animation.

I already tried the following, that did (obviously) not work:

```
_myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(139,193,42,21);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^ {
    _myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(139, 193, 100, 21);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

So what basically happened after running this code was that it changed the width as expected but without any animation.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to explain what did happen, not just that it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, let me add this. Thanks for the advice!
@rdelmar

Comment: @raki
I put it into an IBAction of a button so I should be able to see it...

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the frame size of labels...
You can reach correct animation behavior.. set label.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter but it looks ugly

But you can...:

- change is the bounds, rather than the frame https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304220
- add an UIView and then add UILabel as its subview and animate UIView https://stackoverflow.com/a/15639093 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22224630
- Use a CGAffineTransform to do this but have some ugly side effects like distorting the text on the label https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066366
- change the font of UILabel with transform Animation [Animating UILabel Font Size Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494566/animating-uilabel-font-size-change)