# read html file table in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, core-text

I am creating an application for reading html file .I have searched and found that we can easily convert a html to PDF format ,which is non-editable. And if we are using coretext ,then we can edit the fonts.In the server we are keeping one html file, which includes texts and tables.

**My problems are**

1. How we can I convert the data inside the table?
2. How can I change the fontsize of the text while reading?(same time table should not be broken)

If anybody has idea then please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some code examples?

Comment: for Que-2: put your text in UILabel and you can able to change font size of UILabel by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475513/uilabel-font-size

Comment: @iPatel:I can change the text like that.but I have to change the whole font's size that includes the font inside and outside of the table rows and columns.So the table wil be shown as broken.i have to avoid that